# How do you execute another file when a button is pressed(tkinter) in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a launcher for another program but I just started with Python so I made a button, but I struggle to figure out how to execute another .py file. Any help?

Comment: If it's a .py file there are some ways, one is to put all the code inside the external py file to a function and import that function and call it, but I don't think that is what you want over here

Comment: Or you could try `import subprocess` and then 
`subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py"])`, this could work for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is pressed it activates the `open_file()` function and `os` opens the .py script.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def open_file():
    os.system('python file path here')

root=Tk()

btn = Button(root, text='Open .PY File', command=open_file)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `from subprocess import call`. All you have to do is replace 'YOUR_FILE_NAME' with... your file name :D

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import call

root=Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady=20,padx=20)

def Open():
    call(["python", "YOUR-FILE-NAME.py"])

btn=Button(frame,text='Open File',command=Open)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What it will look like:

[image]

I hope this works for you :D

Comment: This did work, but sadly the other script did exactly what I wanted. But I'm really sorry. And thank you so much for helping me out. I tried both the scripts and decided to stick with the other one. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: That's ok :D I was happy to help